# How does FFmpeg calculate minimum number of bits necessary when converting high bit rate videos to default FFmpeg output settings?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Let's say there's a big video file with high bits rate number. The number is way higher than necessary and I can tell by comparing to other videos with greater quality in terms of sharpness, textures or whatever and also because of the tests I have made with different FFmpeg parameters.

I have learned that simply by re-encoding the file without any settings on FFmpeg will actually decrease the bits and thus outputting a smaller file. The loss of quality is just a little bit noticeable but it's there.

So I would like to know if there is a way that FFmpeg actually calculates the exact minimum number of bits necessary before it makes visible changes to the image quality?

Comment: It's up to the individual encoder and rate control parameters. CRF enabled encoders typically set a default that is trade-off between quality and compression efficiency. This can't be adequately summarized in a SU answer. You would need to study the code for a full appreciation.

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. As Gyan said, this depends on the specific encoder. The concept is called "rate control", and there could be entire books about it. You could have a look at [a blog article](https://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html) I wrote, which is about the CRF rate control mode in x264 and similar encoders.